# Extract data from XML with Google Apps Script into a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: xml, google-apps-script

The purpose of the code below is to extract data from XML files stored in a Google Drive directory. The code returns values ​​for “systemEntries”, but not for “memoryEntries”.

```
function extrairDadosXML() {
  var pasta = DriveApp.getFolderById('pastaId'); // Insira o ID da pasta onde estão os arquivos XML
  var arquivos = pasta.getFiles();
  var planilha = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  
  // Cabeçalho da planilha
  planilha.appendRow(["Manufacturer", "Model", "Serial", "Total Memory", "Total Slots", "Free Slots", "Memory Type"]);
  
  while (arquivos.hasNext()) {
    var arquivo = arquivos.next();
    if (arquivo.getName().split('.').pop() === 'xml') {
      var xml = XmlService.parse(arquivo.getBlob().getDataAsString());
      var root = xml.getRootElement();
      
      var HardwareReport = root.getChild('report').getChild('data').getChild('hardware_report');
      
      var systemEntries = HardwareReport.getChild('entries').getChildren('entry');
      var memoryEntries = HardwareReport.getChild('entries').getChildren('entry');
      
      var manufacturer, model, serial, totalMemory, totalSlots, freeSlots, memoryType;
      
      for (var i = 0; i < systemEntries.length; i++) {
        var entry = systemEntries[i];
        if (entry.getAttribute('name').getValue() === 'manufacturer') {
          manufacturer = entry.getText();
        } else if (entry.getAttribute('name').getValue() === 'model') {
          model = entry.getText();
        } else if (entry.getAttribute('name').getValue() === 'serial') {
          serial = entry.getText();
        }
      }
      
      for (var j = 0; j < memoryEntries.length; j++) {
        var entry = memoryEntries[j];
        if (entry.getAttribute('name').getValue() === 'total_memory') {
          totalMemory = entry.getText();
        } else if (entry.getAttribute('name').getValue() === 'total_slots') {
          totalSlots = entry.getText();
        } else if (entry.getAttribute('name').getValue() === 'free_slots') {
          freeSlots = entry.getText();
        } else if (entry.getAttribute('name').getValue() === 'type') {
          memoryType = entry.getText();
        }
      }
      
      planilha.appendRow([manufacturer, model, serial, totalMemory, totalSlots, freeSlots, memoryType]);
    }
  }
}
```

The reference XML is below:

```
<root>
 <report>
  <data>
   <description>
   ...
   </description>
   <erase_report>
   ...
   </erase_report>
   <hardware_report>
    <entries name="system">
     <entry name="manufacturer" type="string">HP</entry>
     <entry name="model" type="string">HP ProBook 645 G4</entry>
     <entry name="serial" type="string">AB71G</entry>
     <entry name="uuid" type="string">d2e99-0d43-5c</entry>
     <entry name="chassis_type" type="string">Notebook</entry>
     <entry name="asset_tag" type="string">A93</entry>
     <entry name="version" type="string">DBXEnabled</entry>
     <entry name="sku_number" type="string">4C4</entry>
     <entries name="boot_parameters">
      <entry name="boot_parameter" type="string">flr</entry>
      <entry name="boot_parameter" type="string">libata.allow_tpm=1</entry>
      <entry name="boot_parameter" type="string">loglevel=0</entry>
      <entry name="boot_parameter" type="string">memtest=00</entry>
      <entry name="boot_parameter" type="string">rd.udev.log-priority=3</entry>
      </entries>
    </entries>
    <entries name="bios">
    ...
    </entries>
    <entries name="processors">
     <entry name="total_cores" type="uint">4</entry>
     <entry name="total_cpus" type="uint">1</entry>
     <entries name="processor">
      <entry name="id" type="uint">1</entry>
      <entry name="model" type="string">AMD Ryzen 3 PRO 2300U w/ Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx</entry>
      <entry name="vendor" type="string">AuthenticAMD</entry>
      <entry name="nominal_frequency" type="uint">2000000000</entry>
      <entry name="max_frequency" type="uint">3400000000</entry>
      <entry name="cores" type="uint">4</entry>
      <entry name="threads" type="uint">4</entry>
      <entry name="hyperthreading" type="string">false</entry>
      <entry name="stepping" type="uint">0</entry>
      <entry name="voltage" type="string">1.2 V</entry>
      <entry name="external_clock" type="string">100 MHz</entry>
      <entries name="caches">
       <entries name="cache">
        <entry name="type" type="string">Level 1 Cache</entry>
        <entry name="size" type="uint">384</entry>
       </entries>
       <entries name="cache">
        <entry name="type" type="string">Level 2 Cache</entry>
        <entry name="size" type="uint">2048</entry>
       </entries>
       <entries name="cache">
        <entry name="type" type="string">Level 3 Cache</entry>
        <entry name="size" type="uint">4096</entry>
       </entries>
      </entries>
     </entries>
    </entries>
    <entries name="motherboard">
    ...
    </entries>
    <entries name="memory">
     <entry name="total_memory" type="uint">8589934592</entry>
     <entry name="accessible_memory" type="uint">7219544064</entry>
     <entry name="physical_memory" type="uint">8589934592</entry>
     <entry name="total_slots" type="uint">2</entry>
     <entry name="free_slots" type="uint">1</entry>
     <entries name="memory_bank">
      <entry name="vendor" type="string">SMART</entry>
      <entry name="serial" type="string">07D45D</entry>
      <entry name="part_number" type="string">SLSBG</entry>
      <entry name="type" type="string">DDR4</entry>
      <entry name="type_detail" type="string">Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)</entry>
      <entry name="form_factor" type="string">SODIMM</entry>
      <entry name="capacity" type="uint">8589934592</entry>
      <entry name="hz" type="uint">2667000000</entry>
     </entries>
     <entries name="memory_bank">
      <entry name="type" type="string">Empty slot</entry>
      <entry name="form_factor" type="string">Other</entry>
     </entries>
    </entries>
    <entries name="tpm_devices">
    ...
    </entries>
    <entries name="disks">
     <entries name="disk">
      <entry name="id" type="uint">1</entry>
      <entry name="internal_id" type="uint">46</entry>
      <entry name="index" type="string">1 (1-1)</entry>
      <entry name="model" type="string">C56</entry>
      <entry name="vendor" type="string">LITEON</entry>
      <entry name="serial" type="string">00B</entry>
      <entry name="wwnid" type="string">50022ce</entry>
      <entry name="firmware_revision" type="string">V1</entry>
      <entry name="blocksize" type="uint">512</entry>
      <entry name="interface_type" type="string">SATA/SSD</entry>
      <entry name="sed" type="string">Self-encrypting drive</entry>
      <entry name="average_write_speed" type="uint">26463434</entry>
      <entry name="average_read_speed" type="uint">456558742</entry>
      <entry name="capacity" type="uint">256060514304</entry>
      <entry name="sectors" type="uint">5002</entry>
      <entry name="remapped_sectors" type="uint">0</entry>
      <entry name="health" type="string">good</entry>
   </hardware_report>
  </data>
  <user_data>
  ...
  </user_data>
 </report>
</root>
```

I've tried making several changes, but it doesn't work. Either it only extracts data from systemEntries or there is no data returned. How to resolve this?

Comment: When replicating your issue, the script produces an error `"Error on line 108: The element type "entries" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</entries>"` which would mean that the structure of the XML you have is broken. Can you double check your sample XML data you have for us to accurately reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think that your showing XML data is invalid. This has already been mentioned by [SputnikDrunk2's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78123532/extract-data-from-xml-with-google-apps-script-into-a-google-spreadsheet#comment137730571_78123532). But, from your showing script and `The code returns values ​​for “systemEntries”, but not for “memoryEntries”.`, I guess that your actual XML data is valid data. So, I proposed an answer by modifying your showing XML data.

And, when I saw your XML data, it was found that there are 2 `<entries name="memory_bank">` in `<entries name="memory">`. And, there are 2 "type" of `<entry name="type" type="string">DDR4</entry>` and `<entry name="type" type="string">Empty slot</entry>`. But, your script doesn't reflect this. So, unfortunately, I cannot understand your actual expected values. From this situation, I guessed that you might have wanted the 1st element of `<entries name="memory_bank">`.

When your showing script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function extrairDadosXML() {
  var pasta = DriveApp.getFolderById('pastaId'); // Insira o ID da pasta onde estão os arquivos XML
  var arquivos = pasta.getFiles();
  var planilha = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  var header = ["Manufacturer", "Model", "Serial", "Total Memory", "Total Slots", "Free Slots", "Memory Type"];
  var values = [header];

  while (arquivos.hasNext()) {
    var arquivo = arquivos.next();
    if (arquivo.getName().split('.').pop() === 'xml') {
      var xml = XmlService.parse(arquivo.getBlob().getDataAsString());
      var root = xml.getRootElement();
      var HardwareReport = root.getChild('report').getChild('data').getChild('hardware_report');
      var entries = HardwareReport.getChildren();
      var systemObj = entries.find(e => e.getAttribute("name").getValue() == "system").getChildren().reduce((o, e) => {
        var t = e.getChildren();
        if (t.length == 0) {
          var k = e.getAttribute("name").getValue()
          o[k] = o[k] ? [...o[k], e.getText()] : [e.getText()];
        } else {
          t.forEach(f => {
            var k = f.getAttribute("name").getValue();
            o[k] = o[k] ? [...o[k], f.getText()] : [f.getText()];
          });
        }
        return o;
      }, {});
      var memoryObj = entries.find(e => e.getAttribute("name").getValue() == "memory").getChildren().reduce((o, e) => {
        var t = e.getChildren();
        if (t.length == 0) {
          var k = e.getAttribute("name").getValue()
          o[k] = o[k] ? [...o[k], e.getText()] : [e.getText()];
        } else {
          t.forEach(f => {
            var k = f.getAttribute("name").getValue();
            o[k] = o[k] ? [...o[k], f.getText()] : [f.getText()];
          });
        }
        return o;
      }, {});

      var valuesForSystem = ["manufacturer", "model", "serial"];
      var valuesForMemory = ["total_memory", "total_slots", "free_slots", "type"];
      var res = [
        ...valuesForSystem.map(e => systemObj[e] || ""),
        ...valuesForMemory.map(e => memoryObj[e] || ""),
      ];

      // 1st element is used.
      res = res.map(e => e[0]);

      values.push(res);
    }
  }
  planilha.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

- When this script is run, the values are retrieved from each XML file. And, the values are retrieved from `<entries name="system">` and `<entries name="memory">`. And, the retrieved values are put into the Spreadsheet by `setValues`.
- In this answer, the 1st `<entries name="memory_bank">` of `<entries name="memory">` is used. Please be careful about this.

#### Note:

- In this answer, it supposes that your files of XML data are the same structure. If the XML data of the different structures are included in the files, this modified script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.
- If your showing XML is different from your actual one and my proposed modification cannot be used, can you provide valid XML data? By this, I would like to modify it.

Comment: You guessed correctly! It is the first <entries name="memory bank"> element. But if it were the second, what code change would be necessary?

Comment: @Lucas Góes Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question `But if it were the second, what code change would be necessary?`, in this case, please modify `res = res.map(e => e[0]);` to `res = res.map(e => e.length == 1 ? e[0] : e[1]);`. By this, 2nd element is used.

Comment: Still counting on your kindness, "memory_bank" brings data randomly. There are XML that can have up to four "memory_bank" elements. Is there an automatic way to search for information where the "type" attribute is not "Empty slot"?

Comment: @Lucas Góes Thank you for replying. I'm glad your 2nd question was resolved. About your 3rd question, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your 3rd question. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your various questions soon. But, I would like to support you. So, can you post your 3rd question as a new question by including more information? If you can cooperate to resolve your 3rd question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?